# How do I change background entry color when renaming a file, folder etc.?

Tags: 14.04, themes, gtk3

I've been trying lots of workarounds still I cannot find that specific code line for changing that background.

[image]

I looked at solutions [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/136044/how-do-i-change-the-background-color-of-the-menu-bar) and [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162092/how-do-i-change-background-color-of-the-desktop-icon-font) but my problem appears to be slightly different because everything is fine during surfing the files it's only when renaming a folder or a file it becomes grey and with grey-white font so it doesn't look distinctive. What I want is to replace grey background to darker one that's it.

**UPDATE**

I tried a trick to combine/mix this theme with files/codes from other themes just to find out where is it hidden, I replaced gtk2.0 folder with other gtk2.0 theme folder but nothing had changed but when I replaced gtk3.0 folder with the same from other theme the background was black indeed, though the theme appeared afterwards awkward of course but as I far as I can see it's gotta be somewhere in gtk3.0

**UPDATE**

After applying fix:

[image]

Comment: Which theme(s) (and for what version of what desktop) are you using? You could try [changing the selection colour](http://askubuntu.com/q/63126/178596).

Comment: I'm using Delorean Dark 3.10 with Unity standard. The thing is I changed selected color but it's not that as I said it is only when renaming the folder or a file the background is grey.

Comment: Have you tried Trevor answer at http://askubuntu.com/questions/63126/how-do-i-change-the-selected-items-color ?

Comment: If I were in your shoes, I would make backup copies of /usr/share/themes/themename/gtk-3.0 and edit the color codes in gtk-main.css and settings.ini until I got the desired result.

Comment: @ElderGeek thank you for the hint but I know about that I spent like hours searching for that color code and still can't find it so I left it for a while because I got tired of searching... though I know it has to be somewhere there of course. I wrote this question to theme developer and still waiting for the response. I also noticed when googling I'm not the first to ask this around the web there are a couple of questions though no exact answers.

Comment: My solution was to change back to the default theme. Hopefully someone has a better one.

Comment: This might be helpful: http://chipx86.github.io/gtkparasite/ It looks like you could launch nautilus with it and than monitor what happens when you rename a file. No guarantees, but well worth a try.

Comment: @ElderGeek I got interested in that package though I compile and install not for the first time but I cannot finish to install or run this package to the end, could you give me a hint because I don't wanna mess things up. Here's the output http://pastebin.com/Z6L2p9yv

Comment: I figured it out I didn't have some dev-headers installed after I installed them those two errors not found were gone but still it's not working here's the new output http://pastebin.com/Zy2s8guB

Comment: Bugs with gtkparasite are collected here: https://code.google.com/p/gtkparasite/issues/list , **but** i believe your problem is addressed here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12083158/having-trouble-with-setup-py

Comment: thanks for the link to python-tools it's a good one :) though I get: `No local packages or download links found for gtkparasite
error: Could not find suitable distribution for Requirement.parse('gtkparasite')` I guess because example in linked answer for `python-beautifulsoup` package can be even found via synaptic but `parasite` nowhere indeed though if I figure smth out I'll respond. Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After working around for hours with help of theme developer I finally came up with a solution for Nautilus, so to change background entry color when renaming a folder or a file you need to create a small `code` inside theme folder exactly at:

```
sudo -H gedit /usr/share/themes/name-of-the-theme/gtk-3.0/nautilus-entry-section.css
```

and add this code:

```
NautilusCanvasViewContainer.view EelEditableLabel.entry {
background-image: none;
background:black;
}
```

You can edit your way refering to a color even blue or yellow etc... When done, save & close.

Now we should give `gtk-main` a path to read it be named `gtk-main.css` mostly or only `gtk.css`:

```
sudo -H gedit /usr/share/themes/name-of-the-theme/gtk-3.0/gtk-main.css
```

And going all the way to the bottom add at the end:

```
@import url("nautilus-entry-section.css");
```

Save & close it. That's it, done!

Just use a tweak tool to reload a theme.